# Autostart a batch file on Windows

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-server-2003

I want to create a script that will run whenever a server is turned on to do basic things like create a directory and copy a binary from an FTP server to it. I need it to run before a user logs in, as soon as the server is turned on. This will be deployed on my EC2 windows servers.

Checking around (http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial44.html) I saw that only services can run before a user logs in.

I saw that I can make my batch into a com (bat2exe) and set it as a service but that doesn't work with internal commands like ECHO, md, etc.  I can also fake a service to be "cmd /k batch.cmd".

Both seem cumbersome. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Thanks,

Miki

Comment: Why is it in the "amazon" tag?

Comment: Because of EC2, I suppose. Should be irrelevant to the question, though. But proper tagging is something many people can't get right :)

Comment: @1800INFORMATION, removed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Windows Task Scheduler and set it for when the system is booted. Here's more info on that [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28VS.85%29.aspx). Scheduled tasks can run at startup, even before a user logs on (they run in a specified user's context, however).